# How to get innerHTML of a div.id using jQuery, which is updated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

```js
var obj = {
  "Ethernet": "Up",
  "Ethernet": "Down",
  "USB_Dongle": "Down",
  "USB_Dongle": "Down",
  "X_BROADCOM_COM_PPTPAC": "Down",
  "wanLink": "Up"
}

function renderStatusWanLink(obj) {
  var tmp = jQuery('#WAN_Line').html();
  console.log(tmp);

  if (obj !== false) {
    jQuery('#WAN_Line').html(obj.wanLink);
  }
}

renderStatusWanLink(obj);
renderStatusWanLink(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="az-table az-table-status table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>WAN Status</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td id="WAN_Line" width="49%"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to get the html/text content first from inside the div #WAN_Line. initially it will be empty. but then next time it should return me some value as it been updated. but it always returns empty.

HTML: (this is inside one table)

```
<tr>
    <td>WAN Status</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td id="WAN_Line" width="49%"></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
function renderStatusWanLink(obj)
{
    var tmp = jQuery('#WAN_Line').html();
    console.log(tmp);

    if (obj !== false) {

        jQuery('#WAN_Line').html(obj.wanLink);            
    }
}
```

obj =

```
{"Ethernet":"Up",
"Ethernet":"Down",
"USB_Dongle":"Down",
"USB_Dongle":"Down",
"X_BROADCOM_COM_PPTPAC":"Down",
"wanLink":"Up"}
```

Comment: Can you also put your html code and function of updation of div here.?

Comment: @JekinKalariya updated with html code.

Comment: how are you calling renderStatusWanLink

Comment: Please also put how you try to update td value,by calling renderStatusWanLink

Comment: @JekinKalariya please assume that obj.wanLink has some data in it. as it is being populated and can be seen on browser. the obj is json format value returned from ajax call and passed to this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all thing goes right it should work.with your given object and code , below code work perfectly for me. In below code spinet click button to change td html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

var obj={"Ethernet":"Up",
        "Ethernet":"Down",
        "USB_Dongle":"Down",
        "USB_Dongle":"Down",
        "X_BROADCOM_COM_PPTPAC":"Down",
        "wanLink":"Up"};
    function removeLine() {

        var tmp = jQuery('#WAN_Line').html();
        console.log(tmp);

        $('#WAN_Line').html("updated code");
    }


    function renderStatusWanLink()
    {
        var tmp = jQuery('#WAN_Line').html();
        console.log(tmp);

        if (obj !== false) {

            jQuery('#WAN_Line').html(obj.wanLink);            
        }
    }
</script>



</head>
<body>
    <div >

        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>WAN Status</td>

                <td id="WAN_Line" width="49%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button onclick="renderStatusWanLink()">click to change text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes even for me in this code snippet. but not in real application. let me come back with printing obj in console.

Comment: just try to debug your object while network call and put exact value here whatever is comming from network

Comment: found the issue, i think some id name conflict with global html elements, changing it to #WAN_Line1 works. very silly reason. .